# Is ORM framework good to use in RESTFul Web service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, orm, software-design

This question is for software architects,

I have a confusion about to use ORM framework in restful web service, is it good practice?

I'm actually Java Developer working from since 5 years on Java, now doing some software architect stuff, so this confusion is raised, should I use it or not?

please give me pros and cons about it from your experience

Thanks

Comment: ORM frameworks are orthogonal to REST frameworks, they serve totally different needs. The bad architecture would be to use two ORM frameworks in one project, or two different JAX-RS implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is calling down to a SQL DB then it is perfectly reasonable to have an ORM layer.

PRO: simplified coding for simple problem spaces

CON: sub-optimal performance for complex SQL problem spaces

Comment: By the way, "complex SQL" almost always means "bad design"

Comment: I 100% agree.  However flat out saying 'ORM == good' will get you a landslide of down votes from mediocre developers.

Comment: the most crazy real-life sql queries I saw was not result of "mediocre developers" work, but attempts of good developers to adapt existing infrastructure to new needs that the system was not initially designed for. Unfortunately, this happens frequently in enterprise development...

Comment: I wasn't saying that mediocre developers write 'complex' SQL, but rather that they are always the first to hate on ORM

Comment: "bad design" of the query? of the tables? of the indexes?  Generally I feel database queries, and table design are too often left to <insert general purpose development language here> developers and architects rather than to DBA and DB Developers, but just m opinion of course.

Comment: how complex SQL are bad design? If you have 50 tables and you want a report which is getting data from 30 tables then how can you do that? Obviously you have to right complex SQL, and if you do this from JPQL or HQL, that will take too much time to get data from 30 tables, you can imagine it

Comment: I'm not saying its not good for web service, but I'm not getting proper reason to use it, I create generic structure on JdbcTemplate, I just removed the ORM from custom framework design, and added some reflection codes, added batch processing and its working very good

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Lee.
 
It is a totally valid approach using an ORM framework together with Rest (or SOAP).
We use this scenario in a rather large project in conjunction with a service-oriented architecture.

Regarding pros and cons of an ORM framework from my experience:

- while ORM tries to shield the developers from the complexities of SQL, it makes things to easy sometimes, in the way that it lures developers into neglecting things like transaction boundaries and database isolation levels
- if you have developers which already have experience with SQL, you may consider using myBatis
- using JPA/ORM will require some effort to master, but it is quite worth reading a book or taking a course, as using JPA in a suboptimal way will bring down database performance or result in excessive loading of object trees

In the current project we made very good experience with a two day training which will provide you with some tricks and example code how to handle the most common problems and avoid pitfalls.

Comment: I understand what your are saying but ORM not make web service heavy? you can imagine how many object it is creating, I know it can be handle via lazy loading but not everything will be handled from it

Comment: Yes its depends on how much your application is large, yes myBatis sounds good suggestion

Comment: In all cases i have seen when an ORM starts to cosume ressources excessively it was more a problem of a suboptimal use of the framework. The same when it comes to performace - yes it may be faster to use JDBC directly, but consider maintainability when it comes to the need of mapping resultsets to Java Beans, or having to deal with a little bit more complex data structures that have to be persisted in the database.

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct, but what happens when database size becomes 1GB?